# Xcode Build Error Jenkins: Your session has expired. Please log in

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, xcodebuild, xcode10, codesign

I'm trying to build my application using jenkins pipeline using shell command. Below is the command i'm using to build the app.

```
sh 'xcodebuild -workspace projectname.xcworkspace - allowProvisioningUpdates -scheme projectname_UAT -sdk iphoneos - configuration Debug clean build'
```

Below is the error i'm getting i console.

note: Using new build system

note: Planning build

2018-10-11 11:19:36.638 xcodebuild[92399:5181481]  DVTPortal: Service '' encountered an unexpected result code from the portal ('1100')

2018-10-11 11:19:36.638 xcodebuild[92399:5181481]  DVTPortal: Error:

Error Domain=DVTPortalServiceErrorDomain Code=1100 "Your session has expired.  Please log in." UserInfo={payload={type = mutable dict, count = 9,

entries =>

```
0 : responseId = <CFString 0x7ff48deef220 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{contents = "40d9ad44-c951-49da-b3f3-b3ea434765a1"}

2 : <CFString 0x7fff94a90b58 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{contents = "protocolVersion"} = QH65B2

3 : <CFString 0x7ff48dea3420 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{contents = "requestUrl"} = <CFString 0x7ff48de3d9a0 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{contents = "https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/viewDeveloper.action"}

6 : <CFString 0x7ff48dec8c30 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{contents = "userLocale"} = en_US

8 : resultCode = <CFNumber 0x44c37 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{value = +1100, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}

9 : userString = <CFString 0x7ff48ded0cc0 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{contents = "Your session has expired.  Please log in."}

10 : <CFString 0x7ff48dea94d0 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{contents = "resultString"} = <CFString 0x7ff48de648e0 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{contents = "authentication.failed"}

11 : httpCode = <CFNumber 0xc837 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{value = +200, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}

12 : <CFString 0x7ff48de340f0 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{contents = "creationTimestamp"} = <CFString 0x7ff48de9a7d0 [0x7fff94b6daf0]>{contents = "2018-10-11T10:19:36Z"}
```

}

I have even tried removing the developer account from my xcode preferences in local xcode and as well as in my jenkins installed machine. I have re-added it again. Also Deleted the already logged in session from Keychain App in both places(local keychain, remote keychain) But nothing seems to help me out. I'm working with Xcode10, Mac OS Mojave,What might be the issue, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have same problem while uploading through terminal it worked fine but from Jenkins it's failing with session expired not able login error any ideas?

Comment: I'm currently running into the same problem. (Just updated to XCode 10.1 on our Jenkins) Did anyone manage to find a solution yet?

Comment: Any updates here? The same problem...

Comment: I have the same issue and none of the below solutions helped. Anyone with some more hints?

Answer (score 17):

This helped fix the problem with Jenkins running a slave with ssh:

1. Remove the account via Xcode's preferences
2. Quit Xcode
3. Set the preference to not use the keychain service. Type the following in a terminal and hit enter:

`defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTDeveloperAccountUseKeychainService_2 -bool NO`

4. Re-open Xcode and re-add the account

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/112606

Comment: I'd done that last year with success; following an upgrade to Catalina & Xcode 11.4, I needed to remove and re-add the account again.

Comment: Simply re-login the account in XCode fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I'm running into this issue, but only when I run fastlane.  Running the xcodebuild commands that fastlane uses in my terminal does not produce the issue.  I've also tried this on a build machine running Bamboo, but I get a similar result.  In that case the bamboo script can run the xcodebuild commands just fine, but chokes on fastlane.  Any ideas for this situation?

Comment: Same problem here, only in fastlane. @ChristopherShireman did you find a solution?

Comment: @GaryHooper No, I never did.  I have since left the company, and I don't know if they ever fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem as well on one Jenkins build slave dedicated to building one specific app (for iOS and Android).  The Mac was on Mojave and Xcode 10.1

The fix *appeared* to be logging on to the Mac, and exporting the archive created by Jenkins using the Xcode UI, not xcodebuild.  After doing that, the next Jenkins build when through without a problem.  I say appeared to be because I didn't do anything else to the Jenkins job or the slave, and it had been failing consistently before that.  Seems odd, but there you have it.

This specific problem didn't occur on build slaves building other apps, but these other slaves, while using Xcode 10.1, were on High Sierra.  We have had other odd behaviors on all iOS builds since Apple merged Apple Developer and App Store Connect, however.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem for weeks. Since updating to Xcode 10 every aspect of the build Jenkins did would be successful except I would get that error and the build would fail. Directly building, signing, etc. in Xcode was fine.

The solution in my case was the Xcode 10.1 update. The errors you list still exist in the Jenkins output. However it no longer causes Jenkins to fail the build.

Sadly I don't actually know what caused the failure so I don't have any further insight.

Comment: I have the same in Xcode 10.1 :( And I didn't have Xcode 10, but 9.4 before that.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the reason I got this error is because I changed the team manually on my machine and accidentally pushed the changes onto the remote, which cause the Jenkins build failed, but even after I change the team back Jenkins keep failing, after diffing a lot, I found out that `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` filed inside `project.pbxproj` file has to be `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "iPhone Distribution";` other than `="Apple Development"` hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

1. In Xcode Preferences on the build machine, delete the Apple ID and relaunch Xcode
2. Add the Apple ID back
3. Do a build in Xcode GUI <--
4. Build under CI as usual

The upvoted solution (xcode pref setting) by js.mouret had not been successful here. I did have the DVTDeveloperAccountUseKeychainService_2 pref set when I got it working with my steps. I then deleted the pref, re-added my Apple ID again, and was still successful. Why: it seems to me that not using the keychain to store the pref may be less secure. Good luck!

MacOS 12.6.2, Xcode 14.2, non-Jenkins CI system.

Answer (score -3):

I get Error While Running Flutter Project For Session Expire.

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Run Following Command in Terminal
3. Goto Xcode > Preferences > Accounts
4. SignIn Again

```
defaults write -g DVTDeveloperAccountUseKeychainService -bool NO
```