# How to upload to App Store from command line with Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode11

Previously, with Xcode 10, we were using `altool` to upload to App Store:

```sh
ALTOOL="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool"
"$ALTOOL" --upload-app --file "$IPA_PATH" --username "$APP_STORE_USERNAME" --password @keychain:"Application Loader: $APP_STORE_USERNAME"
```

But with Xcode 11, "Application Loader.app" doesn't exist anymore, as part of [the Xcode 11 changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes/):

> Xcode supports uploading apps from the Organizer window or from the command line with xcodebuild or xcrun altool. Application Loader is no longer included with Xcode. (29008875)

So how do we upload from command line to TestFlight or App Store now?

Comment: xcrun supports auto release notes?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

With Xcode 11 as command line tools, to validate or upload an ipa, replace `altool` with `xcrun altool`:

```sh
xcrun altool --validate-app --file "$IPA_PATH" --username "$APP_STORE_USERNAME" --password @keychain:"Application Loader: $APP_STORE_USERNAME"

xcrun altool --upload-app --file "$IPA_PATH" --username "$APP_STORE_USERNAME" --password @keychain:"Application Loader: $APP_STORE_USERNAME"
```

Get more help with `xcrun altool --help`.

Comment: You may need to run `sudo xcode-select -r` at the command line one time before `xcrun altool` will work, in order to select the version of XCode to use. You don't have to manually provide the version, just that line should work. I learned this from a [github issue](https://github.com/electron/electron-notarize/issues/5)

Comment: The **password** is not your Apple account password, but the One-Time (Application) password from https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage

Comment: You may also want to create an API key -> then you don't need username & password at all, just the private key inside the *AuthKey_$APIKEY.p8* file

Comment: For reference, as non-command line solutions, you have either Xcode or [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12).

Comment: @boweidmann are there instructions somewhere on how to do this?

Comment: @fullStackChris just posted a full answer below, hope it helps

Answer (score 35):

Use command line tools,

```
xcrun altool --upload-app -f path -u username -p password
```

If your apple account use TWO-FACTOR Authentication , your password would be wrong , you need to go to **https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage** `"Security - Generate Password"` to get the password

If you get other wrong , you could add `--verbose` to print detail errors log, just like

```
xcrun altool --upload-app -f path -u username -p password --verbose
```

And , get more help with `xcrun altool --help`

Comment: This helped me, but the page at that link has a different format now. You need to click on App Specific Passwords and create one there and use that.

Answer (score 12):

At least as of of Xcode 11, this can be done very easily and directly with xcodebuild, as part of the export workflow.  Just create an exportOptions.plist file that specifies "upload" for the "destination" key and "app-store" for the "method" key.  Here's an example, but of course tune to your needs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>compileBitcode</key>
        <true/>
        <key>destination</key>
        <string>upload</string>
        <key>method</key>
        <string>app-store</string>
        <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
        <dict>
                <key>YOUR_BUNDLE_ID</key>
                <string>YOUR_PROFILE_NAME</string>
        </dict>
        <key>signingCertificate</key>
        <string>YOUR_CERT_NAME</string>
        <key>signingStyle</key>
        <string>manual</string>
        <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
        <true/>
        <key>teamID</key>
        <string>YOUR_TEAM_ID</string>
        <key>thinning</key>
        <string>&lt;none&gt;</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Once you have that, the command to upload an archive to app store connect is very simple, using the xcodebuild **exportArchive** command:

```
    xcodebuild -exportArchive \
               -archivePath PATH_TO_APP_ARCHIVE \
               -exportPath OUTPUT_PATH \
               -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist
```

If you're wondering where your PATH_TO_ARCHIVE is, first just use the xcodebuild **archive** command, e.g.:

```
    xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos \
               -workspace myWorkspace.xcworkspace \
               -scheme myScheme \
               -configuration Release \
               -archivePath PATH_TO_ARCHIVE archive
```

Comment: I set this up recently but now am getting `Failed to log in.` I think I need to get a new app-specific password, but I can't for the life of me remember where you stick the password... Not in `exportOptions.plist`... Where does the password go?

Comment: @mgalgs I've always assumed that the credentials are inherited from XCode by way of the keychain, but I don't know how to solve this problem.  The only think I'd think to try on my own is to restart XCode and make sure that I could upload to app store manually.

Comment: @mgalgs I am facing exactly the same issue (Failed to log in) when executing the command from our CI server. When I run it locally everything works fine so I could only assume that someone should create a temp keychain and import his/her appleId & credentials there. Did you find a solution? (I guess altool would be the plan B in our case)

Comment: Check if the appleId is has logged in the XCode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55699898/1999185

Comment: Would anyone happen to know how to properly authenticate for a GitHub Action? I've spent the last few days troubleshooting, even creating an App Store Connect API key, and that didn't work :(

Answer (score 6):

You can now also use a new app from Apple called "[Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12)"
that is a replacement for Xcode application loader.

Comment: Hello can you help to upload my app using Transporter .. 
i am getting error

Answer (score 2):

Another way to validate/upload the .ipa *without* having to generate one time password every time:

- Go to [App Store Connect console](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/api)
- Generate an API key. Then download the Key(.p8) and copy `Issuer ID` and `KEY ID`.

To validate run:

```
xcrun altool --validate-app -f {YOURAPP}.ipa -t ios --apiKey {YOUR KEY ID} --apiIssuer {YOUR ISSURE ID}
```

To upload to App Store run:

```
xcrun altool --upload-app -f {YOURAPP}.ipa -t ios --apiKey {YOUR KEY ID} --apiIssuer {YOUR ISSURE ID}
```

Comment: To add to this, you'll need to put your newly downloaded .p8 file in one of these locations ~/{PATH_TO_PROJECT_FOLDER}/private_keys', '~/private_keys', '~/.private_keys', '~/.appstoreconnect/private_keys'