# How to upload a signed .pkg built by electron-builder to Apple App store Connect with Xcode 11.0, that has no Application Loader

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-app-store

How to upload a signed .pkg built by electron-builder to Apple MacOS App store Connect with Xcode 11.0, I want to submit my MacOS App to Apple App Store for review and publish.

I make a project with ionic and build it by electron-builder.
and then, the built app was signed by codesign and productbuild, and I got a .pkg file.

But Application Loader is no longer belongs to Xcode 11.0 now.
So how do I upload a .pkg file to Apple Mac App Store with Xcode 11?

Comment: Maybe it can help: [how-to-upload-to-app-store-from-command-line-with-xcode-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56436345/how-to-upload-to-app-store-from-command-line-with-xcode-11). I suggest trying something along the lines of `xcrun altool --upload-app --file "$PKG_PATH" --username "$APP_STORE_USERNAME" --password @keychain:"Application Loader: $APP_STORE_USERNAME"`

Comment: Apple has just released [**Transporter**](https://apps.apple.com/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12) for you to upload such files.