# TeamCity - xcodebuild : encountered an unexpected result code from the portal ('1100')

Tags: objective-c, xcode, teamcity, code-signing-certificate, build-server

I am setting up a new Mac build server. 
But the xcodebuild is falling with error:

```
encountered an unexpected result code from the portal ('1100')
```

I have replicated an existing build steps from an existing configuration and use it on the new server.

I have created a distribution profile and add it to the keychain.

But it keeps falling at this specific step.

```
[11:13:42][Step 4/8] Starting: /Applications/buildA/temp/customscript
[11:13:42][Step 4/8] in directory: /Applications/buildA/work/12345x
[11:13:43][Step 4/8] User defaults from command line:
[11:13:43][Step 4/8]     IDEArchivePathOverride = /Applications/buildA/work/12345x/build/xx
[11:13:43][Step 4/8] 
[11:13:43][Step 4/8] Build settings from command line:
[11:13:43][Step 4/8]     CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Distribution
[11:13:43][Step 4/8]     ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES
[11:13:43][Step 4/8] 
[11:13:44][Step 4/8] note: Using new build system
[11:13:44][Step 4/8] 
[11:13:44][Step 4/8] ** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **
[11:13:44][Step 4/8] 
[11:13:44][Step 4/8] note: Using new build system
[11:13:44][Step 4/8] note: Planning build
[11:13:45][Step 4/8] 2019-07-09 18:14:17.377 xcodebuild[18877:381709]  DVTPortal: Service '<DVTPortalViewDeveloperService: 0x7fabef8693a0; action='viewDeveloper'>' encountered an unexpected result code from the portal ('1100')
[11:13:45][Step 4/8] 2019-07-09 18:14:17.377 xcodebuild[18877:381709]  DVTPortal: Error:
[11:13:45][Step 4/8] Error Domain=DVTPortalServiceErrorDomain Code=1100 "Your session has expired.  Please log in." UserInfo={payload=<CFBasicHash 0x7fabeffcd330 [0x7fffb0813a90]>{type = mutable dict, count = 9,
[11:13:45][Step 4/8] entries =>
[11:13:45][Step 4/8]    0 : responseId = <CFString 0x7fabf0abb590 [0x7fffb0813a90]>{contents = "7215c2e9-29c7-446b-bd4d-c05b938ec56c"}
.............................
............................
```

As per the configuration it was supposed to pass this build successfully with 0 exit code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52757878/341994

Comment: Now I am getting:   `[Step 4/8] 2019-07-09 23:14:15.897 xcodebuild[21197:443969]  DVTDeveloperAccountManager: Failed to load credentials for aaa.aaa@bbb.com: Error Domain=DVTSecErrorDomain Code=-25308 "User interaction is not allowed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=User interaction is not allowed.}`

Comment: In our case Xcode lost the session after an Xcode upgrade and we had to log in again in the Xcode preferences.